# JavaScript is not getting read in the below html code

Tags: javascript, html, animation, dom

I am new to javascript and learning it from a book. I tried opening the webpage with the below HTML and js code. But the javascript part does not seem to be working.
Can someone please let me know on what is missing?

```html
<head>
  <title>Dynamic Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var message = "Learning JavaScript will give your Web
    page life!";
    message += " Are you ready to learn? ";
    var space = "...";
    var position = 0;

    function scroller() {
      var newtext = message.substring(position, message.length) +
        space + message.substring(0, position);
      var td = document.getElementById("tabledata");
      td.firstChild.nodeValue = newtext;
      position++;
      if (position > message.length) {
        position = 0;
      }
      window.setTimeout(scroller, 200);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body bgColor="darkgreen" onload="scroller();">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td id="tabledata" bgcolor="white">message goes here</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: The first thing you should do if you're learning javascript is learn to use the console in the browser. This will show you the errors in your javascript code so you don't have to guess why a page isn't working. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: Are you learning HTML from a book too? If so, throw it away and get a newer one. Your HTML is 20 years old.

Comment: Thanks a lot for enlightening me. I expected that it should be something very basic as you suggested. I will try to debug issues in the browser from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was fine and it works, just minor formatting issues, you can't put break-lines in string literals. Fixed example below:

```js
var message="Learning JavaScript will give your Web page life!";
message += " Are you ready to learn? ";
var space="...";
var position=0;

function scroller(){
  var newtext = message.substring(position,message.length)+ space + message.substring(0,position);
  
  var td = document.getElementById("tabledata");
  td.firstChild.nodeValue = newtext;
  position++;
  if (position > message.length){position=0;}
  window.setTimeout(scroller,200);
}

scroller();
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td id="tabledata" bgcolor="white">message goes here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The new line after

> var message="Learning JavaScript will give your Web

is causing the problem, try to keep this sentence in one line or use the new ES6 multi-line string `` feature

```
var message="Learning JavaScript will give your Web page life!";
```

or

```
var message=`Learning JavaScript will give your
Web page life!`;
```